# use javascript inside php

Tags: javascript, php

for example i want to send email use php and my message obtained from the compound php and JavaScript data...

```
<?php
    $str= "Data: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n\n";

    $str=$str . "system: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";
?>      
<script>
    var txt = navigator.cookieEnabled
</script>
<?php
    //$str=$str . txt
    $str=$str . "cookie: " . $str2;   

    mail($_GET["email"],"New IP",$str);
?>
```

how i can combine the `txt` JavaScript variable with `str` PHP variable???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

- send a request via ajax to your PHP script
- set a cookie in JavaScript and read it in your PHP script

Answer (score 1):

Since Javascript is executed on the client side and PHP is executed on the server site, there is no direct way to use the Javascript variable in PHP. In order to get the value of the Javascript variable, you would have to use some form of AJAX method to send the value of the Javascript variable to server so that the PHP can utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Script tag as string in php,

```
<script>
    var txt = navigator.cookieEnabled
</script>
<?php
    $str=$str . '<script>document.write(txt);</script>'
    $str=$str . "cookie: " . $str2;   

    mail($_GET["email"],"New IP",$str);
?>
```

Comment: tnx ,but it don't work, send `cookie: <script>document.write(txt);</script>` to email! if i echo $str,yes it's work...